# Request after 10 minutes takes more time to load

Tags: apache, tomcat, liferay, squid

I Am facing an issue in web application.

First time the page loads in 5 to 6 seconds. If i keep the browser idle for 10 minutes and then again request or click a tab on web application takes 10 to 15 seconds to load the content.

In this 10 minutes if we are accessing one or the other contents then it wont take much time to load. But if we keep the browser idle for 10 minutes and then try to access it its taking more time to load.

I am using Apache server with default apache configurations.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
    #ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Many things could be the reason, you should try to narrow things down first: Is the client or the server the cause of the lack? What is the load of the client and the server in that 10-15 seconds timespan? Which resource of the page is taking the time (try to use the developer tools of your browser to find that out)?

Comment: I tried to analyse the things using developer tools, only for Home page Cache-control, max age is not getting set. Even If i tried to set it explicitly its not taking. For other pages cache-control , max age and other attributes are getting set, but only for Home page its not. Please let me know to set these attributes.

Comment: What has the max age to do with the load time? If the first request takes 5 to 6 seconds, then the second request usually does not exceed that time, even if it is not cached.